# Tomcat logorate catalina.out

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat

I have been working on logrotate to rotate the tomcat catalina.out in daily basis. I have configured my code in /etc/logrotate.d/tomcat. I have tested my logrotate code by executing manually.The code worked and got compressed catalina.out(.gz). After executing ,now my catalina.out has gone to 0 bytes. So the next time i have executed the logrotate by manually ,catalina.out compressed and the .gz also shows Zero. Can anyone help me with this?
Here is my code,

```
 /opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out
{
daily
dateext
rotate 3
missingok
size 2M
compress
copytruncate
}
```

Comment: Send your code in a more explanatory way, missing your code

Comment: Hi Hasan, to be more clear, 1. Logrotate works perfectly and my catalina is being compressed as .gz file.                                                                                                   2. After execution now my primary catalina show 0 bytes .                                        
3. Everytime i have to restart my tomcat to bring back the primary catalina for logs. 4. then repeating step 1 as follows. How to overcome this??